# MySQL assign query value into variable

Tags: mysql

I made procedure listed below:

```
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE processPayment(in id int(11), status int(11)) 
BEGIN 
declare msg_a text DEFAULT "Payment was marked as sent";
declare msg_d text DEFAULT "Payment was marked as denied and user balance was updated";
declare msg_w text DEFAULT "Wrong payment status";
declare msg_u text DEFAULT "Wrong payment ID";
declare amount varchar(255) DEFAULT 0;
amount = "SELECT amount FROM payments WHERE id = id";
user_id = "SELECT userid FROM payments WHERE id = id";

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM payments WHERE id = id AND status = status) = 0
THEN
SELECT msg_u;
END IF;

IF(status = 0)
THEN
SELECT msg_w;
END IF;

IF(status = 1)
THEN
UPDATE payments SET status = status WHERE id = id;
SELECT msg_a;
END IF;

IF(status = -1)
THEN
UPDATE payments SET status = status WHERE id = id;
UPDATE balances SET actual = actual+amount WHERE user_id = user;
SELECT msg_d;
END IF;

END
```

But when i try to add it into database i get error:
 Something is wrong in your syntax near '= "SELECT amount FROM payments WHERE id = id"; user_id = "SELECT userid FROM pa' line 8
I need to assign query value into variable.
How can i do this?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways in order to achieve this. First with SET :

```
SET amount  = (SELECT amount FROM payments WHERE id = id);
SET user_id = (SELECT userid FROM payments WHERE id = id);
```

Or with the SELECT INTO syntax :

```
SELECT amount INTO amount FROM payments WHERE id = id;
SELECT userid INTO user_id FROM payments WHERE id = id;
```

You can even achieve it in one line with this second method :

```
SELECT amount, userid INTO amount, user_id FROM payments WHERE id = id;
```